# Select the last img in 2 divs with the same class

Tags: html, css, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have two divs with the same class `.productList`, and want to manipulate the second `<img>` in both divs with jQuery.

I have the following;

```
$('div.productList').each(function(){
    $('img:last-child').css('margin-left','10px');
});
```

Markup (partial)

```
<div class="productList">
<img src="images/parts/" width="120" height="120" alt="" title="" />
<img class="last" src="images/parts/" width="120" height="120" alt="" title="" />
```

I assumed using `.each()` would cycle through each div and find the last `img`, but this is not working for me.

Could someone please point me in the right direction with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this via JS and not CSS? `div.productList img:last-child { margin-left: 10px }`

Comment: please show some sample mark up

Comment: Markup added. There is no reason for jQuery over CSS. In this instance I want to use jQuery

Comment: I can see a `last` class there. What's the problem then? Simply use the class selector (`.last`).

Comment: I was trying to avoid using that class, instead using jQuery to target the img

Comment: @webworker You can use jQuery to target that img, using the class :). I'm starting not to understand what this question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "Better" Pure CSS Ways

I agree with Ethan that you should just use CSS to do that, however, using the `last-child` selector (as he recommends) will only work if the `img` tag is in fact *the last html element in* `.productlist` (i.e. no other `div`, `span`, etc. follows the `img` tag--[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/RVc4g/)). Since you only showed partial markup, that is entirely unclear to me. If it is simply a series of `img` tags, then use Ethan's answer, otherwise...

**A better CSS3 solution** is to use `last-of-type`, as it will only look for elements of the type that is being sought (`img` in this case). So if other elements follow it, [it does not matter](http://jsfiddle.net/RVc4g/2/).

```
.productList img:last-of-type {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**For Older Browsers not supporting CSS3**, if your two `img` tags in fact sit one after another in your mark-up, and they are the only paired up `img` tags in the `.productList`, then a solution for those older browsers (which also would work in newer, CSS3 browsers) would be to [use the adjacent sibling selector](http://jsfiddle.net/RVc4g/3/):

```
.productList img + img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was adverse to a CSS solution at first, but this works well.

Answer (score 5):

Just use css to do that:

```
div.productList img:last-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It is possible for this solution to fail, as [this fiddle illustrates](http://jsfiddle.net/RVc4g/), depending on the specific html mark-up (which @webworker did not post the entirety of). I've posted some additional solutions to avoid those difficulties, should that be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Either use CSS to do it like Ethan has said, but if you're doing it in jQuery **there is absolutely no need for the .each statement**. Just use jQuery to select the last item:

```
$('.productList img:last-child').css('margin-left','10px');
```

See it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Willyham/PM8eG/

CSS solution:

```
div.productList img:last-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.productList').each(function(){
  $('img:last', this).css('margin-left','10px')
});
```

**CSS solution:**

```
div.productList img:last-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vx9c9/2/)

```
   $('div.productList').each(function(){
        $(this).find('img:last').css('margin-left','50px');
   });
```